# Access and Display Returned data from Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've searched much but did'nt find any answer for my problem.

I am new to angularJs so please explain in easy way...

i am using a library for social media login ...everything is working fine.. but i want to access and store the returned data from directive in a variable and also want to display that data in div accordingly.

following is code of directive:

```
socialLogin.directive("fbLogin", function($rootScope, fbService, social, socialLoginService){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, ele, attr){
        ele.on('click', function(){
            fbService.login().then(function(res){
                if(res.status == "connected"){
                    fbService.getUserDetails().then(function(user){
                        socialLoginService.setProvider("facebook");
                        var userDetails = {name: user.name, email: user.email, uid: user.id, provider: "facebook", imageUrl: user.picture.data.url}
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('event:social-sign-in-success', userDetails);
                        console.log(userDetails);
                    }, function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                }
            }, function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

})

in console, console.log(userDetails) is display as object now i want to display the data of object in div accordingly and also want to store all data in variables accordingly in variables to send in database...

Please help me in easy way i am new in angular js.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change  scope: {} to  scope: false
This is the default value of scope in the directive definition. In this case, the directive has the same scope as its parent controller. 
Now create a userDetails object in your controller scope which will get initialized after FB login.

```html
socialLogin.directive("fbLogin", function($rootScope, fbService, social, socialLoginService){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, ele, attr){
        ele.on('click', function(){
            fbService.login().then(function(res){
                if(res.status == "connected"){
                    fbService.getUserDetails().then(function(user){
                        socialLoginService.setProvider("facebook");
                        scope.userDetails = {name: user.name, email: user.email, uid: user.id, provider: "facebook", imageUrl: user.picture.data.url}
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('event:social-sign-in-success', userDetails);
                        console.log(scope.userDetails);
                    }, function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                }
            }, function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can use $scope.userDetails.

Comment: i have tried code above and then access data from controller but still get undefined in console.

Comment: Try making scope : true, 
As scope: true is useful in situations where the child directive serves the purpose of mutating data on the parent scope.